# Advanced query in SQL

Tags: sql

If I have a table that contains a date (`dd-mm-yy`) column and request column with 2 values (success or error), and want to query the following:

- On which days (`dd-mm-yy`) did more than 1% of requests lead to errors?

Comment: You should tag your questions with the database you are using and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do use conditional aggregation:

```
select date,
       avg(case when request = 'error' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_errors
from t
group by t
having avg(case when request = 'error' then 1.0 else 0 end) >= 0.01;
```